# C++ sprintf and cyrillic symbols, VS2019, Linux

Tags: c++, linux, sqlite, utf-8, cyrillic

I'm working with sqlite3 from VS2019 with remote gcc on Linux.
I need to create a query to a database, I'm using sprintf.

```
BOOL MwProtonProtocol::GetObjectindexByTypename(const char* ObjectTypeName, int &iObjectIndex)
{
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;
    char* sQuery;
    
    //!!!!!!!!here!!!!! But I've got the problem!!
    sprintf( sQuery, "SELECT objectindex FROM ObjectTable WHERE objecttypeindex IN(SELECT objecttypeindex FROM ObjectTypeTable WHERE objecttypename = '%s')", ObjectTypeName);
    int res = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_pDatabase, sQuery, -1, &stmt, 0);
    
    if (res == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        GlobLogPrintf("ZemonDBArch.sqlite ObjectTable is READ");

        while ((sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) || (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_OK))
            iObjectIndex = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 2);

        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

...

  int iObjectIndex(0);
  const char* ObjectTypeName("Фотон-1");
  if (GetObjectindexByTypename(ObjectTypeName, iObjectIndex))
  {
     //do something 
  }
```

If ObjectTypeName contains English text, I get the right string in sQuery. But if it's Russian, then I got this in the variable:

[image]

and in sQuery Cyrillic symbols looks like this:

[image]

How to get the right Cyrillic string??

Comment: `sqlite3_prepare_v2` expects a UTF-8 encoded string, but "Фотон-1" might not be UTF-8. That depends on your source file encoding. If you are using C++17 or higher, please consider using the u8 prefix

Comment: [UTF-8 Cyrrilic](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_cyrillic.asp).  Also as mentioned, that string-literal may not contain the actual non-ASCII characters you see inside the quotes.  The editor that you're using allowed you to enter those characters, but the actual source encoding may give you something different.

Comment: You shouldn't be building queries using strings anyway, use placeholders in your query and pass the parameters into `sqlite3_bind_text` (this also gives you the option to use encodings other than utf-8)